# set content of an empty span

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file (template to messages) with empty spans:
 
I want the text of the span dynamically change according to specific msg that I choose.
I run this from a main.html file that inside there is empty div with id "empty".
message1 is an array.

this is the script:

```
if(msgArray[i] == "message1")
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#empty").load(message1.template);

    for(var j=0; j<message1.text.length; j++)
    {
      $("#templateText"+(j+1)).text(message1.text[j]);
    }
  });
```

}

in debug it looks fine but when I run it its not working.
what could be the problem?

Comment: If `message1` is an array, then `message1.text` and `message1.template` don't make sense. That expects it to be an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you load inside `#empty` are the fields you're trying to fill in, you need to use a completion handler because it involves an asynchronous request behind the scenes:

```
$("#empty").load(message1.template, function() {
    // fields are now ready to populate
    for (var j=0; j<message1.text.length; j++) {
        $("#templateText"+(j+1)).text(message1.text[j]);
    }
});
```

See also: [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/)